# how do i get content of microsoft word file 2016 in php laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ms-word

I am trying to get file word 2016 content in my controller
using IOFactory
here is my code

```
$phpWord = IOFactory::createReader('Word2007')->load($request->file('add_file')->path());

       foreach($phpWord->getSections() as $section) {
                    foreach($section->getElements() as $element) {
                        if(method_exists($element,'getText')) {
                            echo($element->getText() . "<br>");
                        }
                    }
                }
```

and that is the result

```
    PK!ߤ�lZ [Content_Types].xml �(����n�0E�����Ub袪*�>�-R�{V��Ǽ��QU� l"%3��3Vƃ�ښl  �w%�=���^i7+���-d&�0�A�6�l4��L60#�Ò�S O����X��*��V$z�3��3������%p)O�^����5}nH"d�s�Xg�L�`���|�ԟ�|�P�rۃs��?�PW��tt4Q+��"�wa���|T\y���,N���U�%���-D/��ܚ��X�ݞ�(����K/����4�Vm^u�r��w2NP�0ŮVw�5�j��o����7o:>S!?p����8JX[d�0KD��EVK���c2�P,���ũ�a���]���.���ﰘs�Yҡ�+�����(!O>z���PK!�`n�b#word/document.xml�Z�n�F��;,x�EI�dY��vb�P@��sA�+�0�%�+��NdYP{�45Z9���?p�d�6�Y����T��h��ݝ�曙ݏ�G�w\�t)l�U�\&��̲�VU�����Fax��0�V�]h��?
��Q�b1��RO���J�7�Z[���٦�d\��,`M�1���f�6��c����\V����4 ކ�u�@��̝��,n����6��;S�ܭA���^� �^O��ԃ�&�!`�[�k�펿��!���b ���U��*1�� �T"*�%���č\6�v��:�p`^ж�IMݏE��v��P]�I�z~�p� �ue �����1�0b.�@Gb����    װ�i��*�Lqs����z;�b����h���ݺ��Yǟ��wC{�mO�P�n���܍L�m�p�]���1n4`�'�>�:@�h렦 f���'� �����e������5-��q�\][)g�L&7i��8�ym�X!׸��Ů�+]éj�NC�¡��k<2�s&�E%xN��ó!6 �I���df#���cD}�ϧ�e�F�{#�J�p5��U�Ӫ��    ��9 (�Rm�\�A9��{���\2@�<�u��|/��yA�8�}�����'N�#�3y�����Q��'����x��k"���p�ȟ�B| h�8��<&���   �_f��    ��"|
����G0��1�j�0��"�;����H#�^8Z�ɗ0�=��* ;D�Q>�ȷ����S  �C���C���{L'�W�}
```

Comment: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

Comment: @RossWilson this link for writing and saving a word file . i want to read a content of a word file and display its content in the view

Comment: The description for the repo is "A pure PHP library for **reading** and writing word processing documents". Either way the package is using `IOFactory` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what class is returned by `getElements()` you won't have access to `getText()`. Something like the following should do thew trick:

```
$phpWord = IOFactory::createReader('Word2007')->load($request->file('add_file')->path());

$text = [];

foreach ($phpWord->getSections() as $section) {

    foreach ($section->getElements() as $element) {

        switch (get_class($element)) {
            case 'PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\Text' :
                $text[] = $element->getText();
                break;
            case 'PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\TextRun':
                $textRunElements = $element->getElements();
                foreach ($textRunElements as $textRunElement) {
                    $text[] = $textRunElement->getText();
                }
                break;
            case 'PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\TextBreak':
                $text[] = " ";
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception('Something went wrong...');
        }
    }
}
```